# Creating a plan in braintree is giving 500 internal server error in php

Tags: php, braintree, braintree-sandbox

I am trying to create a plan in my braintree sandbox but it is giving me 500 internal server error. Creating plan via php because i want to test 1 day recurring payment so that i can perform my rest operation.

here is my code

```
Braintree_Configuration::environment(BRAINTREE_ENVIRONMENT); // Change to production
Braintree_Configuration::merchantId(BRAINTREE_MERCHANT_ID);
Braintree_Configuration::publicKey(BRAINTREE_PUBLIC_KEY);
Braintree_Configuration::privateKey(BRAINTREE_PRIVATE_KEY);
    
try{
    $plan = Braintree_Plan::create([
          'name' => 'My Example',
          'price' => '10.00',
          'billingDayOfMonth' => 1,
          'billingFrequency' => 1,
          'numberOfBillingCycles' => 12, // Number of billing cycles, or set to 0 for indefinite
          'trialDuration' => 0,
          'trialDurationUnit' => Braintree\Subscription::TRIAL_DURATION_UNIT_DAY
      ]);
      echo'<pre>';print_r($plan);die;
    }catch(Braintree_Exception $e){
        echo 'Some error: ' . $e->getMessage();
    }
```

If this is right code to achieve what i want then what would be porblem?

The error I am getting is

> Call to undefined method Braintree\Plan::create()

Comment: 500 Internal Server Error is a generic error message informing you that the server crashed while processing the request. Beyond that, it's (intentionally) meaningless, and is of very little use for debugging. You need to check the error logs on the server (or enable on-screen error reporting, if it's a development environment) to try and find the underlying exception message. Once you've got that, you stand a chance of identifying the problem, and then moving on to trying to fix it.

Comment: That said...you have some code there to catch an exception. Is it not catching the exception and outputting the message? If not, then it's quite likely that the error doesn't originate from within that try/catch block.

Comment: If I am commenting my try catch block then error disappear. As soon as enable, it occurs.

Comment: It would appear that the `Plan` class doesn't have a `create()` method then. I'm not familiar with this specific library. Is there some documentation for it, and/or some usage examples?

Comment: https://developer.paypal.com/braintree/docs/reference/request/plan/create/php

Comment: Ok thanks. So in the examples it uses `$gateway->plan()->create(`.  Any reason you don't do it like that?

Comment: I tried both method but the result is same.